Blazor server, Static SSR page, Enhance forms not working
I build a test page with two forms:
@page "/ssr"
@layout StaticSSRMainLayout
@attribute [ExcludeFromInteractiveRouting]
@using BlazorPageScript
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Text
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
@using BlazorApp9.Data
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>SSR Page</PageTitle>

<PageScript Src="./Pages/Tests/StaticSSR/StaticSSRPage.razor.js"></PageScript>

<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <EditForm Model="Input" FormName="show-email1" id="showEmail1Input" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmitAsync" method="post" Enhance>
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" id="showEmail1Input" />
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Show1</button>
            </EditForm>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <EditForm Model="Input2" FormName="show-email12" id="showEmail2Input" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmitAsync2" method="post" Enhance>
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="Input2.Email" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" id="showEmail1Input2" />
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input2.Email" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Show1</button>
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <RadzenAlert Variant="Variant.Filled" AlertStyle="@AlertStyle.Info" Size="@AlertSize.Medium" Shade="Shade.Light" AllowClose=true Text="Message">
            @message
        </RadzenAlert>
        <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.DisplayH3" TagName="TagName.H3" class="rz-display-flex rz-mt-2 rz-my-0">
            Email: @email
        </RadzenText>            
    </div>
    <div>
        <RadzenAlert Variant="Variant.Filled" AlertStyle="@AlertStyle.Info" Size="@AlertSize.Medium" Shade="Shade.Light" AllowClose=true Text="Message">
            @message2
        </RadzenAlert>
        <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.DisplayH3" TagName="TagName.H3" class="rz-display-flex rz-mt-2 rz-my-0">
            Email: @email2
        </RadzenText>            
    </div>
</div>

@code {
   
    string message = null;
    string email = null;    
    int id = 5;

    string message2 = null;
    string email2 = null;   
    int id2 = 5;


    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "show-email1")]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "show-email12")]
    private InputModel2 Input2 { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();        
    }

    private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
    {
        email = Input.Email;
        message = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";
        id = 114;
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    }


    private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync2()
    {
        email2 = Input2.Email;
        message2 = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";
        id2 = 114;
    }

    private sealed class InputModel2
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    }


    public async void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

I use blazor.web.js in App.razor, but Enhance forms is not working. When send a form and part of the page is updated, when I send the second form, the first form and its update clear and vice versa.
So how to enable enhanced form updates in blazor?
EDIT: in the network tab I see a fetch request is made, so it is working, but when the entire @code{..} block is executed, what is the benefit?! every thing is reset again! the good way is: just the relevant OnValidSubmit() executes.

I solved this problem like this:
<PageTitle>SSR Page</PageTitle>
    
    <PageScript Src="./Pages/Tests/StaticSSR/StaticSSRPage.razor.js"></PageScript>
    
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <EditForm Model="Input" FormName="show-email1"
                          OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmitAsync1" method="post" Enhance>
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3" data-permanent>
                        <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                        <label class="form-label">Email</label>
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Show1</button>
                </EditForm>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <EditForm Model="Input2" FormName="show-email2"
                          OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmitAsync2" method="post" Enhance>   
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3" data-permanent>
                        <InputText @bind-Value="Input2.Email" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                        <label class="form-label">Email</label>
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input2.Email" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Show2</button>
                </EditForm>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="up1" data-permanent="@pu1">        
            <h4>@message</h4>
            <h4>Email: @email</h4>
        </div>
    
        <div id="up2" data-permanent="@pu2">        
            <h4>@message2</h4>
            <h4>Email: @email2</h4>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    @code {
    
        string message = null;
        string email = null;
    
        string message2 = null;
        string email2 = null;
    
        bool pu1 = true;
        bool pu2 = true;
    
        [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "show-email1")]
        private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();
    
        [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "show-email2")]
        private InputModel Input2 { get; set; } = new();
    
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await base.OnInitializedAsync();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    
        private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync1()
        {        
            pu1 = false;
            email = Input.Email;
            message = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";    
        }
    
        private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync2()
        {        
            pu2 = false;
            email2 = Input2.Email;
            message2 = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";    
        }
    
        private sealed class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; } = "";
        }
    
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

And in the PageScript file:
export function onUpdate() {
    console.log('Page Updated'); 

    var up1 = document.getElementById("up1");
    var up2 = document.getElementById("up2");
    if (!up1.hasAttribute("data-permanent")) {
        $(up1).attr('data-permanent', '');
        // up1_OnSuccess code
    }
    if (!up2.hasAttribute("data-permanent")) {
        $(up2).attr('data-permanent', '');
        // up2_OnSuccess code
    }
}

Thanks to 'Ruikai Feng' for note on data-permanent attribute.

You need to add data-permanent attribute:
<div class="form-floating mb-3" data-permanent>
    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" id="showEmail1Input" />
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
</div>

For more details,you could read this doc

the entire @code{..} block is executed

Since there exists ssr componets in your app,it would be in static routing instead of interactive routing ,see this doc
If you want just the relevant OnValidSubmit() executes,  configure the render mode of your whole app as interactive server
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />


Someone with a previous experience of Unobtrusive Ajax in MVC3,4,5 (that was static ssr rendering), may expect to see something as capable as that. we could put many Ajax forms and links on the page, and they worked. But this one is a totally crippled tech, we even can't put two Enhance forms on one SSR page that each one updates part of the page and that update is retained after posting another!

Have you tried data-permanent attribute ? Append it to both two , Itwould keep the updates in another form for you

yes, it causes no update to the div, even when its relevant form post, it retains the initial values.

Oh,I see,you may try interactive server mode instead.there's already a similar issue on github:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54117
